# Move UIButton 10px down and open new ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I'm newbie at iOS development and this is my first question on SO.

I want to create "animation".

When I tap UIButton I want to slowely (about 0.5 seconds) move it down for 10px and when I raise my finger I want to open new viewController.

I made *something* but I don't know how to make "animation".

```
    UIImage *normalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstImage"];        
    UIButton *firstButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(31, 194, normalImage.size.width, normalImage.size.height);
    [firstButton setImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [firstButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showSecondViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:firstButton];


- (void)showSecondViewController; {
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    secondViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
    [progressViewController release]; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:^(void) {
    //put your animation result here
    //then it will do animation for you
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    //do what you need to do after animation complete
}];
```

for example:

```
UIButton *firstButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

//add firstButton to some view~
//....

firstButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void) {
    firstButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,10);
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    show your view controller~
}];
```

Comment: Thanks @IPaPa but my button is "automatically animated". When I run my app it is automatically moved for 10px. Where I'm wrong?

        UIImage *normalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstImage"];        
        UIButton *firstButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(31, 194, normalImage.size.width, normalImage.size.height);
        [firstButton setImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
        [self.view addSubview:firstButton];

Comment: firstButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void) {
            firstButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,10);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
            //show your view controller~
        }];

Comment: did you put the animation code in the button TouchUpInside callback?

after you do [UIView animation.....],animation will run immediately

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations: ^ {
  button.frame = CGRectMake:(button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y + 10.0f, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put transformations(repositioning), scaling and rotatations between beginAnimations and commitAnimations blocks where you can specify the AnimationRepeatCount,AnimationCurve etc.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
..........................//etc.

firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(31, 194, normalImage.size.width, normalImage.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But in iOS4 and later animations are encouraged to be performed by

animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:compeletion and similar methods that invlove blocks which are very powerful. For more information on block animations please refer to apple documentation